Azure AD OAuth2 redirect_uri issue with varying behaviors for different users
Description
I am encountering an issue with the OAuth2 authentication flow in an application using Azure Active Directory. The application functions correctly for some users during the login process, granting access tokens as expected. However, for other users, the process fails with an invalid_grant error, specifically pointing out that the redirect_uri does not match the one used to obtain the authorization code, despite using the same redirect_uri consistently.
Obtaining the Authorization Code
The authorization code is obtained via a redirect to Azure's authorization endpoint. Here's how the request is structured in the frontend using environment variables to secure sensitive details:
const responseType = process.env.VITE_AZURE_RESPONSE_TYPE; = 'code'
const scope = process.env.VITE_AZURE_SCOPE; = 'api://client-id/demo'
const clientId = process.env.VITE_AZURE_CLIENT_ID;
const oauthUrl = process.env.VITE_AZURE_OAUTH_URL; = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
const responseMode = process.env.VITE_AZURE_RESPONSE_MODE; // 'query'

const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:5173/auth/login';
const url = `${oauthUrl}client_id=${clientId}&response_type=${responseType}&scope=${scope}&response_mode=${responseMode}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)};

relevant part of the code where the issue occurs:

public function loginAD(Request $request)
{
    $url  = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $data = [
        'client_id'     => 'client-id',
        'scope'         => 'scope-url/demo',
        'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost:5173/auth/login',
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'code'          => $request->code
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(data));

    $response = curl_exec(ch);
    $decodedResponse = json_decode(response, true);

    curl_close(ch);

    if (isset(decodedResponse['access_token'])) {
        session()->put('token_sso', decodedResponse['access_token']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized 1'], 401);
    }
}

Azure Microsoft Entra Id Settings:
While the process worked as expected for most users, some users encountered an invalid_grant error during the authentication process. The error message suggested that the redirect_uri does not match the one used to obtain the authorization code. However, I have verified that the redirect_uri is consistent throughout the authentication process.

if you are using custom scope, external accounts get invalid grant error

What should I do? Inactivate the scope in Azure and remove the scope from the request body?

I'm not quite sure about this option. If you're an admin of that external tenant, you can register that application in your tenant. Then, the invalid grant error won't occur.

It didn't work for me. the same error still occurs. even if I define scopes as User.Read
